# Graphical Multiple Linear Regression in Stata

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-regression, stata

Consider this standard linear regression model:

$Y = \beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\cdots+\beta_pX_p+\epsilon$

I've loaded such a dataset into Stata 12.0, so I have some variables $y,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p$. How do I produce a plot, like I would with `. scatter y x` for a simple linear regression model?

Comment: Do you mean `scatter y x || lfit y x` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about how to do something in Stata, not about Statistics. If there's an underlying statistical matter you want help on, please edit the post to make it clear.

Comment: @Scortchi and voters on closure: I think there is a statistical question deep inside this as well as a Stata question, so I'd suggest keeping it open. The focus should be: exactly what goes on what axis, and is this a single or a multiple plot?

Comment: @NickCox et al. Let's ask Newb. Newb, do you know what you want to graph and just not know how to do it in Stata? Or do you want to know about good graphics for this sort of situation, and then you can figure out the Stata code on your own? Or both?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73320/how-to-visualize-multi-linear-regression) then.

Comment: This hasn't been clarified....

Comment: My question was about whether it's possible to compose all $\beta_1 X_1 \ldots \beta_P X_P$ into a single $X$-variable, and then to conduct simple linear regression.

Comment: You would need to get the $\beta_j$ first. If that's by estimation, it is multiple regression and not to be followed by a simple regression. If that's otherwise, you could do that.