# Clarifications regarding reading a nomogram

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, predictive-models, regression-strategies

Following is a nomogram created from mtcars dataset with rms package for the formula:

```
mpg ~ wt + am + qsec
```

[image]

The model itself seems good with R2 of 0.85 and P<0.00001

```
> mod

Linear Regression Model

ols(formula = mpg ~ wt + am + qsec, data = mtcars)

                Model Likelihood     Discrimination    
                   Ratio Test           Indexes        
Obs       32    LR chi2     60.64    R2       0.850    
sigma 2.4588    d.f.            3    R2 adj   0.834    
d.f.      28    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    g        6.456    

Residuals

    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4811 -1.5555 -0.7257  1.4110  4.6610 

          Coef    S.E.   t     Pr(>|t|)
Intercept  9.6178 6.9596  1.38 0.1779  
wt        -3.9165 0.7112 -5.51 <0.0001 
am         2.9358 1.4109  2.08 0.0467  
qsec       1.2259 0.2887  4.25 0.0002
```

I am not clear what are these 'Points', 'Total Points' and 'Linear Predictor'. Which one of these represent mpg, the outcome variable? I will appreciate any explanation.

Edit: considering excellent suggestions by @Glen_b for easy reading of points etc, following could be an alternative nomogram:

[image]

Since outcome or response variable is available, it can be used instead of the term 'Linear Predictor'. It also become self-explanatory as to how the nomogram needs to be read.

Comment: nice diagram in edit there

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, since your model is linear, with the expected mpg equal to the linear predictor, you can read mpg straight off the linear predictor scale.

For each variable, you find its value on the relevant scale. For example, imagine we wanted to find a predicted mpg for a car with `wt=4, am=1, qsec=18`:

[image]

which gives a predicted mpg of about 18.94. Substituting into the equation gives 18.95, so that's pretty close. (In practice you would probably only work to the nearest whole point -- and so get about 2 figure accuracy - "19 mpg" - out, rather than 3-4 figures as here.)

One of the chief benefits of such a diagram to my mind is that you instantly see the relative effect of changes in the different predictor variables (IV) on the response (DV). Even when you don't need the diagram for any calculations, it can have great value in terms of simply displaying the relative effects of the variables.

---

Followup question from comments:

> Does it work the same way for non-linear or polynomial regressions?

For cases where $E(Y)$ is nonlinear in some predictors, some minor - and perhaps obvious - modifications are needed. Imagine that we have $\hat{y} = b_0+b x_1+f(x_2)$

where either:

(a) $f$ is monotonic; or

(b) $f$ is *not* monotonic

In either case, the scale for $x_1$ would work exactly as above, but in case:

(a) the scale for $x_2$ won't be linear; e.g. if $f$ is monotonic decreasing but (roughly) quadratic, you might have something like this:

[image]

(b) the non-monotonic scale for $x_2$ will "break" at a turning point and flip over. e.g.

[image]

-- here the function $f(x)$ has a minimum somewhere around $x=2.23$

It's possible for such functions to have several turning points, where scales would break and flip over multiple times - but the axis line only has two sides.

With points-type nomograms this presents no difficulty, since one may move additional scale-sections up or down (or more generally, orthogonally to the direction of the axis) a little until no overlap occurs.

(More than one turning point can be a problem for alignment-type nomograms; one solution shown in Harrell's book is to offset all the scales slightly from a reference line, on which the value's position is actually taken.)

---

In the case of GLMs with nonlinear link function, the scales work as above, but the scale of the linear predictor will be marked with a *nonlinear* scale for $Y$, something like (a) above.

Examples of all of these situations can be found in Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*.

---

---

Just a couple of side notes

1. I'd much prefer to see *two* points scales, at the top and bottom of the relevant section; otherwise it's hard to "line up" accurately because you have to guess what 'vertical' is. Something like this:

   [image]

   However, as I note in comments, for the  last section of the diagram (total points and linear predictor) perhaps a better alternative to a second points scale would be to simply have a pair of back-to-back scales (total points on one side, linear predictor on the other), like this:

   [image]

   whereupon we avoid the need to know what 'vertical' is.
2. With only two continuous predictors and a single binary factor, we can quite readily construct a more traditional *[alignment nomogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomogram)*:

   [image]

   In this case you simply find the `wt` and `qsec` values on their scales and join them with a line; where they cross the `mpg` axis, we read off the value (while the `am` variable determines which side of the `mpg` axis you read). In a simple case like this, these kind of nomograms are faster and simpler to use, but can be less easy to generalize to many predictors, where they can become unwieldy. The points-style nomogram in your question (as implemented in *Regression Modeling Strategies* and in the `rms` package in R) can add more variables seamlessly. This can be quite an advantage when dealing with interactions.

Comment: Thanks for a clear, illustrated explanation. Does it work the same way for non-linear or polynomial regressions?

Comment: I have edited my answer to respond to this additional question.

Comment: This is an amazing post Glen.  I think I'm going to modify the `nomogram` function's `plot` method to add the extra `Points` scale by default.  Great suggestion!!

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for your kind words. For the last section of the diagram (total points and linear predictor) perhaps a better alternatve to a second points scale would be to simply have a pair of back-to-back scales (total points on one side, linear predictor on the other).

Comment: Neat idea and would save space.  Or should it be Points and Total Points back-to-back?

Comment: @FrankHarrell No, because you don't read any relationship between points and total points - they needn't even be on the same page. The problem is finding 'vertical' so you can read from total-points to the linear predictor accurately. If those two scales are very close or touching, rather than say two inches apart, it's not an issue. When they're inches apart, a few degrees of error in finding vertical can mean a fair bit of error in the result. You still need two points scales in the first section though, because you can have many predictors and they can't all be adjacent to the points scale.

Comment: @FrankHarrell : please see my edit with diagram.

Comment: Well, I guess they can, if you replicate a points scale for each predictor. There are some reasons (cleaner visual comparison of effect sizes) why a second point scale at top and bottom might be better, but for just reading the values rnso's scale replication is lind of nice.

Comment: @Glen_b interesting idea to put a points scale with every predictor's axis.  I wonder if that is going to get too busy when there are 15 predictors or when a predictor interacts with a 10-level categorical predictor.  The only remedy I can think of is to put each points axis and their tick mark labels in gray scale.  But that is still fairly busy looking.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I agree; that would only work with a few predictors. But the Points scale at both the top and bottom of all the scales would still work; it might be a better default.

Comment: If Points scale is only on the sides, a vertical grid should be provided for easy checking of points for each predictor.

Comment: There has long been an option for that.  I wonder if that solves the issue other than adding a duplicate points scale at the bottom.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Personally I think a grid clutters the display, and tends to obscure its value; I avoid grids when I can. They also don't allow the same degree of precision in getting vertical unless the grid is as fine as the scale (which I think would be terrible visually), Without an option for one, I'd end up editing in a second points scale (just as I did here) to get it to be in what I'd see as a usable state for the two purposes I see it having (i. making reasonably accurate estimation of predicted values without obscuring  ii. the clarity of the relative contributions to the response)..

Comment: I can't figure out how  the "points" related to the logodds? could you explain @Glen_b

Comment: Read Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*.

Comment: @Glen_b: Do you happen to know what formula should be used to retrieve the predicted value of mpg from nomogram information?  Let's say we know the predictor values (i.e., wt = 4, am = 1, qsec = 18) and can use the nomogram to derive the corresponding Total Points for these values.  We also know the Points per unit of linear predictor from the nomogram.  What formula can we plug this information into to get the predicted value of the response variable mpg?  Does this formula rely on the Intercept of the ols() model?

Comment: No formula is needed, that's the point of it. With the simpler kinds of nomograms for only a few predictors you can just read the predictions directly off their scale. With ones with more than a couple of predictors sum the points, then read the prediction off from the prediction scale. A nonidentity link function can be encoded directly into that scale. You should never need to do anything harder than adding points