# Visualizing a regression with 1 DV and multiple IV

Tags: r, regression, interactive-visualization

I am working on a paper, attempting to explain the effects of certain influences on terrorist organizations with regards to politicizing.  Using VISREG I am able to create visualizations to depict each regression when I have 1 DV and 1 IV.  When I attempt to visualize the script below, I get an error.  Any suggestions?  Also, I am very new to R and R studio.  I have only been working with this program for 3 months.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Ended Through Politics model
m5 <- glm(Politics ~ Peak.Size + 
            Lifespan..0.recoded.to.1 + Any.Negotiation.with.Government+
            govmil + Economy + FreeScale + Right.Wing +
            Left.Wing + Nationalist + Religious + Regime.Change +
            Territorial.Change + Policy.Change + Empire + Social.Revolution +
            Status.Quo, data=main, family="binomial")
```

Comment: I'm not trying to be pedantic, but by VISREG, do you actually mean `visreg`? If yes, `visreg(m5)` should work, at least according to [this description](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/publications/visreg.pdf) of the package (link opens PDF).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73320

Answer (score 2):

A partial residual plot (also known as component+residual plot) is usually the way to go. It shows the relationship between each predictor variable and the response variable given that other predictor variables are also in the model. In **R** you can do it with the `crPlots` function in the `car` package or the `prplot` function in the `faraway` package.

Using your example and the `crPlots` function, you could try:

```
library(car)
crPlots(m5)
```

You might want to narrow it down using `crPlots(m5, terms = [...])`.